# Failing the test

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a test case using `JUnit` and I want to fail my test by catching an `exception`. The method under test throws `DataException` and catches `Throwable`. In my test case I want to catch `DataException` but my test passes if I don't fail it.

Method under test:

```
public List<DataSet> retrieveData(String action, Map<String, Object> params, ServiceContext ctx) throws DataException {
    List<DataSet> o = null;
    try {
        if( FIND_BY_AGENCY_CODE.equals( action ) ) {
            o = findByAgencyCode( params );
        } else if( GET_CHILD_AGENCY_CODE.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getChildAgencies( params );
        } else if( GET_VALID_VALUES.equals( action ) ) {
            o = loadValidValues( params );
        } else if( GET_VALID_VALUE_COMBO.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getValidValueCombo( params );
        } else if( GET_CLAIM_UNITS.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getClaimUnits( params );
        } else if( GET_SP_LIMIT.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getSPLimit( params );
        } else if( GET_SP_PIP_APIP_TYPE.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getSPPipApipType( params );
        } else if( GET_SP_DEDUCTIBLE.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getSPDeductible( params );
        } else if( GET_SP_COVERAGE.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getSPCoverage( params );
        } else if( GET_SP_FORM_DISPLAY.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getSPFormDisplay( params );
        } else if( GET_CLAIM_UNIT.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getClaimUnit( params );
        }  else if( GET_SP_STATE_COMPANY.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getSPStateCompany( params );
        } else if( GET_SP_COV_LIMIT_LOOKUP.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getSPCovLimitLookup( params );
        } else if( GET_SP_UND_LOOKUP.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getSPUnderwriterLookup( params );
        } else if( GET_SP_UND_BRANCH.equals( action ) ) {
            o = getSPUndBranch( params );
        }
    } catch( Throwable t ) { 
    }
    return o;
}
```

JUnit Test:

```
@Test
public void testRetrieveData() {
    try {
        AppContext.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        IRetrievable dao = (IRetrievable)AppContext.getBean( "nextGenDao" );

        ServiceContext ctx = new ServiceContext();

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put( ServiceConstants.AGENCY_CODE, "1234" );

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        List<DataSet> ds = dao.retrieveData( NextGenDao.FIND_BY_AGENCY_CODE, params , ctx );
        fail();
    } catch (DataException t) {
        assertNotNull(t);
        assertEquals("Unit Test", t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am not exactly sure if this is the right approach to accomplish such a thing, but this is what I got so far.

Thanks

Comment: and your questions is what exactly?

Comment: You never throw the exception from your method. You just catch it and do nothing.

Comment: The method under test never throws any exception. Why do you think your test should pass (if that's what you're thinking - it's a bit confusing)?

Comment: Worth a look: https://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/conditionDispatcherWithCommand.html

Comment: Method throws DataException.

Comment: Well, the method may be declared to throw that exception, but actually it never will.

Comment: @Yousuf the method **declares**, in the throws clause, that it **can** throw a DataException. But it never actually does. Read t[he Java tutorial on exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 1):

In your method under test, there is no possibility of it throwing anything, ever. Having all the code surrounded by a try block with `catch (Throwable t) {}` means that anything extending Throwable (meaning all possible Exceptions and Errors) will get caught and eaten. So if you expect the test to catch a DataException, that won't happen. What will happen is that if an exception is thrown within the method, the list the method returns will be null.

Comment: If add throw new DataException(t) in the catch block. Would it possible to catch the DataException then.

Comment: @Yousuf: sure, because in that case your method would actually be throwing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the test to fail after catching an exception put a fail() statement in the catch block in your test.

If you want the test to fail if it doesn't throw an exception, use the @Test(expected = DataException.class) annotation for that test.